# rails not initializing unsaved nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model structure as follows:

```
class Client
  belongs_to :lead
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lead
end

class Lead
  has_one :client
  has_many :defense_practices, through: :some_join_model, source: :practice, source_type: "DefensePractice"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :defense_practices
end
```

I have a form structure has follows:

```
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :leads do |lead_builder|
    <%= f.fields_for defense_practices do |practice_builder|
      <%= practice_builder.text_field :some_field %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The data is submitted correctly in the params hash:

```
Parameters: {
    "client"=>{
       "lead_attributes"=>
           {"id"=>"45",
            "defense_practices_attributes"=>
                 {"0"=>{
                           "some_field"=>"some_value",
                           "id"=>"52"
                       },
                  "4"=>{
                            "some_field"=>"some_value"
                       }
                  }
             }
        }
   }
```

The second practice was added through javascript, using the same technique used in the railscasts nested model form.

When the models are initialized in the create action, the defense practice which was added through javascript (which is unsaved as shown by the lack of an id attribute in the hash above) is not initialized:

```
  def create
    @client = Client.new client_profile_params
    puts @client.lead.defense_practices.size # => 1
  end

  def client_profile_params
    params[:client].permit!
  end
```

One special note: In Client model, I had to override lead_attributes= because I have an unsaved client model with a saved lead model and if I did not override, then rails complains: Couldn't find Lead  with ID=46 for Client  with ID=.

```
  def lead_attributes=(params)
    if params[:id].present? 
      lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
      self.lead = lead
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

It should initialized two defense practices. But it only initialized the defense practice which was already associated with that lead. It did not add the new defense practice to the association. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see your `client_profile_params`?

Comment: def client_profile_params
    params[:client].permit!
  end @JTG

Answer (score 0):

This is what I call a ripple effect. One limitation in Rails leads to using a hack which unleashes a can of worms. Because the Lead was created before the Client, I couldn't save the Client with an existing Lead. So I had to override the Rails core lead_attributes= method in my model. Well, by doing that it circumvented a lot of the Rails internals. I was able to grab it back by using update_attributes and passing in the params hash:

```
  def lead_attributes=(params)
    if params[:id].present?
      lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
      lead.update_attributes params
      self.lead = lead
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, this is giving rise to new problems, but it does resolve the question that was asked.